# How to make node address a bootndoe address?

Tags: go-ethereum, bootnodes, enode

when I add node enode address to bootnode other node only connect to node assigned in bootnode

Comment: Sorry, but your question is a bit hard to understand. Could you try to be a bit more verbose?

Comment: I have created a private ethereum network and added enode address in bootnodes.go.
when I run another node it peer with the enode specified in bootnode.go but other node will not peer with each other